# PATH Variable Changed By Accident

Tags: cygwin, environment-variables

I am a super newb when it comes to this so take it easy on me.  I recently ran a commend when installing cygwin to try and get python to run properly.  The command I ran was:

```
echo "PATH=\$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Python36" >> .bash_profile
```

Afterwards I ran this command as well:

```
PATH=\$PATH:/usr/bin/home
```

Now every time I start up Cygwin, I get the following information to popup at the top:

```
-bash: /home/Chris/.bash_profile: line 45: syntax error near unexpected token `'
-bash: /home/Chris/.bash_profile: line 45: `=PATH=//usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/iCS Client:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/Sstem32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Proram Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/IntelIntel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/IntelIntel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/IntelR) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cgdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cygdrive/c/Users/Chri/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/cygdrive/c/Users/Chris/AppData/Local/atombin:/cugdrive/c/Python36'
```

I clearly messed something up, any help would be amazing.

Comment: So edit your .bash_profile, look to see what's wrong on line 45, and correct it. We can't do it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Your bash_profile should contain this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/home
```

Note the \ was removed.  You can append your other paths to the above line.